# Testing whether or not a flag has an argument

Tags: bash, getopts

My typical setup for parsing command-line options is:

```
CONF=""
INPUT=""
while getopts ":c:i:" FLAG; do
   case $FLAG in
      i) INPUT=$OPTARG;;
      c) CONF=$OPTARG;;
      \?) echo -e "\nInvalid option: -$OPTARG"
         usage;;
      :) echo -e "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
         usage;;
   esac
done
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    usage
fi
```

I'm looking for a way to catch when a valid flag is provided but no argument is - for example:

```
./Script.sh -c -i
```

Returns `usage`. I was under the impression that this line:

```
:) echo -e "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
```

Handled this however when running the script as above using flags without arguments, the usage function is not firing nor is the echo.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke your script with either `./script.sh -c -i -c` or `./script.sh -c`, both will show the error message `Option -c requires an argument.`

However, when invoking `./script.sh -c -i`, you are passing value "-i" for the `-c` argument, so that at the end of arguments parsing, you end up with `CONF=-c` and `INPUT not set`.

Comment: Ah yes - of course. I'm guessing there's probably no easy around this?

Comment: You can workaround it by either checking that OPTARG *matches* another existing flag, but I am affraid `getopts` does not provide this itself.